# Hide rows based on multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I need to hide rows in excel based on the value of multiple cells in the same row. If my row contains all 0's or is blank I need it hid. If there is any integer (not 0 or neg) I need the row shown. On the same sheet I have 'section headers' that separate sections, and below that, a row of blanks. Can I leave those intentional blanks in? I've had a few partially working lines written out, I just can't get it all together.

[image: Basic layout]

Hope this make sense and thanks for any help!

Edit: Now if I have a hidden column I'd like for the 'sum' to disregard the hidden column. I've tried nesting something inside RowanC's answer but no go.

```
For Each myRow In hideRange.Rows
  For Each cell In hideRange.Cells
      If cell.Columns.Hidden = False Then
          Total = Total + cell.Value
      End If
  Next
  If Total = 0 Then 'if the sum of the row=0 then hide
      myRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If
Next
```

Comment: `If there is any integer (not 0 or neg) I need the row shown` I think 0 fit nicely to your requirement. So you only need to test if Sum of your row value is > 0; if false hide it. Oh, and @RowanC posted an answer like such.

Comment: found the solution. specialcells(xlcelltypevisible) Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quick go at it:

```
Sub rowHider1()
    Dim hideRange As Range
    Dim myRow As Range

    Set hideRange = Sheets(2).Range("A2:D12") 'you must set this to apply to the range you want (you could use active selection if you wanted)
    hideRange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide any rows currently hidden
    For Each myRow In hideRange.Rows
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRow) = 0 Then 'if the sum of the row=0 then hide
            myRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

to take this a step further, and if a column is hidden, don't include it in the sum, moving away from worksheetFunction sum:

```
Sub rowHider()
Dim hideRange As Range
Dim myRow As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim bob As Double
Set hideRange = Sheets(2).Range("A1:G12") 'you must set this to apply to the range you want (you could use active selection if you wanted)
hideRange.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide any rows currently hidden
For Each myRow In hideRange.Rows
    bob = 0
    For Each cell In myRow.Cells()
        If cell.EntireColumn.Hidden <> True Then
        Debug.Print cell.Address & "   " & cell.Value
            bob = bob + cell.Value
        End If
    Next
    If bob = 0 Then 'if the sum of the row=0 then hide
        myRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and I thought I understood it until I tried to disregard the value in any cell that was in a hidden column. I've tried nesting a For Each Cell inside your answer, but no luck. Thank you so much!